# Is there a way in JavaScript to instantiate an object which is not necessarily a function?

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming, prototype-programming

My prototypical example is the following pseudo-code:

```
var kind = ...;
...
var type = new kind();
...
var person = new type();
...
var john = new person();
```

But the problem here is that `type` is not a function so `new type()` won't work.
Is there an specific property that you can add to an object to make it acceptable to `new`?

What most matters to me is the prototype chain, that is what matters for me, that is `person.[[Prototype]]` should be `type`, etc, in case that is not possible with `new`.

Creating a subtyping chain is not an option. Here `type` is the meta-type of `person`, not its supertype. Likewise `kind` is a meta-meta-type. The following tests may clarify the requirements:
When all done, I want these positive tests:

```
console.log(john instanceof person);   // should be true
console.log(person instanceof type);   // should be true
console.log(type instanceof kind);     // should be true
```

*and* these negative tests:

```
console.log(john instanceof type);     // should be false
console.log(john instanceof kind);     // should be false
console.log(person instanceof kind);   // should be false
```

I hear that by assigning to the `__proto__` property one can do some magic of this sort, but don't know how. Obviously a portable solution (by using `Object.create` for example) is much preferred, if there is one.

Comment: So are you simply trying to create a `person`, which is-a `type`, which is-a `kind`?  So every time you're making a new `person`, you're implicitly making a new `kind`, and automatically getting all the features of that type?

Comment: No I don't want a subtyping chain, I want `person` to be instance of `type` in the same way that `john` is instance of `person`.

Comment: This is confusing, especially with your comment on FunkyFresh's answer.  1) You want an is-a relationship between the types? 2) You don't want to inherit any structure or functionality from the base type?

Comment: I updated the question to clarify this issue. Does this make sense now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an specific property that you can add to an object to make it acceptable to `new`?

No. The property that controls this ability according to ECMAScript section 11.2.2 is called `[[Construct]]`, and as you can tell from the square brackets, it's an internal property. It can't be influenced from ECMAScript code. The only time `[[Construct]]` gets assigned is, according to section 13.2, when a Function object is created.

The only access you have to prototypal inheritance in ECMAScript Third Edition is through creating constructor functions with a `prototype` property. You have to create the function even if you don't intend to do anything with it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1595611/18936) covers common patterns of class/instance systems.

In ECMA 5 you indeed get `Object.create()`. For compatibility with current browsers that don't support it yet, you can implement that part of `Object.create()` yourself using a temporary constructor function that does nothing, eg:

```
if (!('create' in Object)) {
    Object.create= function(proto, props /* optional */) {
        var obj;
        if (proto===null) {
            obj= {};
        } else {
            Object.create._construct.prototype= proto;
            obj= new Object.create._construct();
            Object.create._construct.prototype= null;
        }
        if (props!==undefined)
            Object.defineProperties(obj, props);
        return obj;
    };
    Object.create._construct= function() {};
}
```

(Of course `Object.defineProperties` is another ES5 method that you'd have to shim in if you wanted support for that, and that's not possible to implement in plain ES3, only using other browser extensions.)

> I hear that by assigning to the `__proto__` property one can do some magic of this sort, but don't know how.

This was always non-standard, and is going away even in Firefox. Don't bother with it.

Comment: I hope something like `Function.create(proto, f)` exists as well, returning a function equal to `f`, but with the given prototype. Then I could say `type = Function.create(kind, function() {})`

Comment: @saintali: Not natively. You can certainly implement one yourself in very little code, though, eg `var type= kind.makeSubclass()` in the linked question.

Comment: `__proto__` is going away everywhere, not just in Firefox. Still will be around for a bit until all the use-cases addressed by it are possible with other stuff, though. (The intention is for the [[Prototype]] of an object to become immutable at object creation time.)

Comment: @bobince I don't see how `kind.makeSubclass()` solves that problem. I want `type instaceof kind` but not `new type() instaceof kind`. As I said in the updated question, I want `type` to be the (meta-)type of `person` and `kind` to be the (meta-meta-)type of `type`.

Answer (score 0):

try `new type.constructor()`, which will create a new object of the same type as `type`, that may be what you want.

Comment: `type.constructor` is `kind`, so this will create a new `kind`, not a new `type`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want `type` to inherit `kind`? yes?

if so...

```
function kind() {};
kind.prototype.name = "fred";
function type() {};
type.prototype = new kind();

var person = new type();
colsole.log(person.name);  //fred

console.log(person instanceof type);  // true
console.log(person instanceof kind);  // true

console.log(type.prototype instanceof kind);   //true
```

Comment: I want this `instanceof` chain to be true: `john instanceof person && person instance of type && type instance of kind`

Comment: See update. As you can see person is an instance of all the types it inherits from.

Comment: Thanks, but `person instanceof kind` is problematic, please see the updated question.