# Old object as a prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I'm reading [this](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do) book and there is a chapter about prototypes with this hard to understand paragraph and code snippet.

> When you make a new object, you can select the object that should be
>   its prototype. The mechanism that JavaScript provides to do this is
>   messy and complex, but it can be significantly simplified. We will add
>   a beget method to the Object function. The beget method creates a new
>   object that uses an old object as its prototype.

```
if (typeof Object.beget !== 'function') {
     Object.beget = function (o) {
         var F = function () {};
         F.prototype = o;
         return new F();
     };
}
var another_stooge = Object.beget(stooge);
```

Could you please explain this code, why is this good etc.? Which resource would you recommend to study prototypes? Here is it quite difficult.

Comment: Check out this SO answer which explains in detail about javascript prototypal inheritance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript/1598077#1598077

Comment: @xralf javascript good parts is a hard read tough to understand. I also share the same feeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do:

```
Object.beget(oldObject);
```

The old object is the o passed to the function. The next thing is the creation of the new object. This happens with:

```
var F = function(){};
```

This creates new function F, capitalized just to show it is meant as a class that should be called with new.
Next the old object is set als the prototype of this class and a new instance of F is returned.

```
F.prototype = o;
return new F();
```

What you should realise is that, in JavaScript (not having classes), objects are just instances of functions.

Comment: I think you mean `o` instead of `0`.

Comment: *objects are just instances of functions* ... that's not true. When you call `new Func()`, then `this` inside function refers to an empty object which inherits from `Func.prototype`. That's all. Or maybe you just mean something different than I understand it :)

Answer (score 1):

I always found the MDN doc on JavaScript instructive, for me, this one covers prototyp well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model

Comment: Thank you, I will read it. I have seen this about a week ago but the site was corrupted or something, so I avoided this but now it's readable.