# the better way to implement OOP in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to do a framework (academically) animations in JavaScript and Canvas, I began to look for guides DONE of object-oriented programming with javascript and I find too many variations.

examples:

```
// Example 1
var object = {
  public_method: function(){ //do something }
}

// Example 2
function object(){
  this.public_method = function(){ //do something }
}
var o = new object();
```

which is the correct or best way (simple and light) to do so.

note: that good design pattern for this kind of project?

Comment: Neither; the first form does not use JavaScript's prototypal inheritance, the second form creates a new closure for each object instance.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to read through the accepted answer on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript) SO question.

Answer (score 4):

The first will only create one single instance, while the second can be used to create several instances.

I prefer using a constructor function and putting the methods in the prototype. That way the methods are created once for all instances instead of created separately for each instance:

```
function ExampleObject() {
  this.answer = 42;
}

ExampleObject.prototype = {
  get_answer: function(){ return this.answer; },
  another_method: function(){}
};

var obj = new ExampleObject();
alert(obj.get_answer());
```

Comment: Recommend that you clarify the difference between setting functions in the prototype versus creating closures for each object instance in the 'constructor'. Also strongly recommend you use something other than `Object` in your example.

Comment: @Guffa I would also recommend that you at least mention of global namepspace/variable pollution danger that comes with your method.

Answer (score 3):

If you want something that will be similar to the classic OOP design (which revolves around *classes*), you should do something like this:

```
function MyClass(param1, param2) {
    this.param1 = param1;
    this.param2 = param2; // These are fields.
}
MyClass.prototype.publicMethod = function() {
    // do something
}
var o = new MyClass(x, y);
```

I suggest you read more about `prototype`. This enables you creating many instances of the same "class", without wasting memory, execution and programming defining the methods for each instance separately.