# Instancing new objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, instance, literals, javascript-objects

I'm probably missing something really basic on javascript knowledge, but why doesn't this work?

```
var person = {

    name:"",
    age:0,

    set : function(name,age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

var me = new person; // ERROR: Object doesn't support this action!
me.set('Victor',12);
me.name //Victor
```

---

But this does:

```
var person = function(){

    this.name="";
    this.age=0;

    this.set = function(name,age){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }
}

var me = new person(); //WORKS!
me.set('Victor',12);
me.name; //Victor
```

Comment: Yes, only the second one works. Why/how would the first one work? You need a constructor function to call new on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "properly" create a custom object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Your first example was an object literal:

```
var person = {
    name: "Bob",
    //etc
};
```

You've created a single object called person, and that's that.  The concept of creating **new** persons has no meaning.

If you want to create something that can be used to create more objects at will, you'd use a function, like your second example.

Note though that functions intended to be used as a constructor start with a capital letter by convention.  Also note that when you set a function inside of your constructor using

```
this.functionName = function() .....
```

this creates a *privileged* function, since it has access to both public, and private members.  If this set function only needs access to public properties, it would usually be added to the function's `prototype`.  Here's how the whole thing might look

```
function Person() {
    this.name = "";
    this.age = 0;
};

Person.prototype.set = function(name,age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

And here's what a privileged method might look like

```
function Person() {
    var localData = "Hello";

    this.showPrivateData = function() {
        alert(localData);
    };

    this.name="";
    this.age=0;
};
```

`localData` is local to the `Person` function, and cannot be accessed as a property on instances of Person; however, the `showPrivateData` function, and any other privileged functions you might add, would form a *closure* over it, and have access to it.

Finally, note that constructor functions can take parameters:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name= name;
    this.age= age;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has no classes (although you can *simulate* them), this is why. And `new` works only on functions (in this case it creates special variable `this` inside function, which is being returned implicitly after function call).

So, when using this:

```
var person = {
    name:"",
    age:0,
    set : function(name,age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
};
```

you already create an object (which has a function as one of its properties).

But when you use this:

```
var person = function(){
    this.name="";
    this.age=0;
    this.set = function(name,age){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }
};
```

you only create function, that returns `this` with all assigned properties when the function is called with `new`.

### What documentation says

As [documentation of `new` operator on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/new_Operator) says:

> The `new` operator creates an instance of a user-defined object type or of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function.
>
> ...
>
> Creating a user-defined object requires two steps:
>
> - **Define the object type** by writing a function.
> - **Create an instance** of the object with `new`.

and you basically make both steps in the second case.

Comment: I almost always write like the second but all IDEs only autocomplete methods and properties in the first way, so I tried to "translate" a class to object literal, to my code could be auto completed. Any thoughts to workaround this issue?

Comment: @Vitimtk: You are incorrect, at least in NetBeans you are able to write `var A = function(){this.test='ABC';};var a=new A();` and when writing `a.` in `alert(a.test);`, you are given a list of properties (with `test` among them, with proper tip about it being declared in `A`). It looks like it does not even need plugins for this.

Comment: In Aptana Studio doesn't work for me, I tried document my class with ScriptDoc without success... I'm so mad about this.

Comment: @Vitimtk: Aptana Studio is not "_all IDEs_". Maybe you should consider changing your IDE or helping [Appcelerator](http://aptana.com/company)  [expand Aptana with this feature](http://aptana.com/contribute)?

Answer (score 1):

You answer your own question. A constructor (the thing that goes next to `new`) must be a function in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The first version uses an object literal to create a single object instance which is assigned to `person`. This cannot be used like a constructor with `new` to create other objects from `person`.

The second version uses a function, which *can* be called as a constructor to create new objects with `new person()`.

That's just the way `new` works in JavaScript. Essentially if you want to be able to create multiple instances from a template (similar to how classes work in other languages) then use the `new FunctionName()` syntax. If you only need to create a single instance of a particular object you can use the first syntax.

Note that in the first version you can say:

```
person.set('Victor',12);
alert(person.name); // 'Victor'
```

Note also that if you are creating a function that is intended for use as a constructor the convention is to use uppercase for the first letter of its name (or the first letter of each word in the name).