# "Object doesn't support this action" when "newing" a nested Javascript object instance

Tags: javascript, object, instance, javascript-objects

I have created a "Namespace" of sorts using nested objects in Javascript and am trying to "new' up an instance of a javascript object.

```
//
// Create the ABC.DTO "namespace"
if (typeof (ABC) == 'undefined') var ABC= { DTO: {} };
//
// Define the ListType object
ABC.DTO.ListType = function (pId, pName) {

    var id   = pId;
    var name = pName;

    return {
        Id: id,
        Name: name
    }
};
//
// Create an instance of the "listType" object
var type1 = new ABC.DTO.ListType(1, 'Letter Type'); // THROWS ERROR
```

The error being thrown is "Object doesn't support this action" ... I have reviewed the following posts and, unless I am missing something I feel like the code is conformign correctly. Am I overlooking something?

[Define a “nested” object constructor in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051148/define-a-nested-object-constructor-in-javascript)

[Instancing new objects in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570834/instancing-new-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Shoulldn't it be ABC.DTO instead of GMCR.DTO?

Comment: I see a different error: [`Uncaught ReferenceError: GMCR is not defined`](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Tntqd/).

Comment: Yeah that was a typo. I have fixed in in the OP. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 0):

This works in the most simple case:

```js
baz = { foo: {} };
baz.foo.bar = Function;
bop = new baz.foo.bar();

console.log(bop);
```

And the slightly more complex case:

```js
var baz = { foo: {} };
baz.foo.bar = function(){};
var bop = new baz.foo.bar();

console.log(bop);
```

But fails in the aforementioned case due to hoisting.

**References**

- [JavaScript variables hoisting in details](https://rainsoft.io/javascript-hoisting-in-details/)
- [A Dangerous Example of Javascript Hoisting](http://ignaciothayer.com/post/a-dangerous-example-of-javascript-hoisting/)
- [JavaScript is Hard Part 2: The Hidden World of Hoisting | Platformability](http://blog.caplin.com/2012/01/18/javascript-is-hard-part-2-the-hidden-world-of-hoisting/)