# Referring to a javascript object

Tags: javascript

Looking at some sample javascript code at http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/api/autoloader.html  I see:

```
<script src="shCore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="shAutoloader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
SyntaxHighlighter.autoloader(
  'js jscript javascript  /js/shBrushJScript.js',
  'applescript            /js/shBrushAppleScript.js'
);

SyntaxHighlighter.all();
</script>
```

In this example, what is a SyntaxHighlighter?  a global variable?  a singleton?  a what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax highlighter might be an object literal with a method named all. This is generally done to organize functions into namespaces to avoid populating the global namespace. It might be defined as such: Check out this 
http://jsfiddle.net/PQbEU/2/

```
syntaxhighligter = {
    all: function(inputColor) {
        if (!inputColor) 
            inputColor= prompt("Enter a color");
        $('#all').css({
            background: inputColor
        });
    }
}
syntaxhighligter.all();​
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/SyntaxHighlighter/blob/master/scripts/shCore.js - it's a function which returns an object.  It's a JavaScript code-organization pattern.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1598077/18255

http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth