# Javascript: new vs return object

Tags: javascript, node.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function vs. Object Literal Notaion - is there a diifference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079544/function-vs-object-literal-notaion-is-there-a-diifference)

I'm playing around in nodejs and I got to a place where I can do the same thing in two different ways.

```
var x = function(arr) {
    this.get = function(index) {
        return arr[index];
    }
}
var myVar = new x([1,2,3,4]);
```

or

```
var y = function(arr) {
    return {
        get: function(index) {
            return arr[index];
        }
    }
}
var myVar = y([1,2,3,4]);
```

There's obviously some difference between these two methods, my question is which?
Thanks

Comment: they have different scopes and one returns an object while the other adds a method... you can do individual research on both of these changes through stackoverflow.

Comment: Wow, nice find of a duplicate.