# What is the best way of defining a class in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have searched for a way of defining a class in javascript like in java or php but I found none!

I want something like

```
class javascriptClass {

       function someFunction(){}

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 5):

You can use a prototype class, like so:

```
function MyClass() {

}

MyClass.prototype.method1 = function() {
    // do stuff
};

MyClass.prototype.method2 = function(p) {
    // do stuff
};

var myClass = new MyClass();
```

Now, after instantiating an object myClass from the prototype MyClass, you can access the methods of the object myClass:

```
myClass.method1();
```

The above method is great if you need to instantiate more than one object/instance of the class.

If you only expect to have one object, then another method you can use simply acts as a namespace to protect your functions from collisions with others:

```
var myObject = {

    method1: function() {
        // do stuff
    },

    method2: function(p) {
        // do stuff
    }
};

myObject.method1();
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, you don't have classes as such. You define functions that are used to create objects with `new`, and you can give them methods by either creating them in the body of the constructor, or adding them through the object's *prototype*. For example:

```
function JavaScriptClass() {
    // I am a JavaScript constructor! Any initialization can be done here.
}

// This is the prototype! You can put instance methods and variables (to an extent) here.
JavaScriptClass.prototype.someFunction = function() {
    alert('someFunction was called!');
};

// Now, let's create an instance!
var obj = new JavaScriptClass();
obj.someFunction(); // someFunction was called!
```

And you can access the current object using `this`, in both the constructor and any methods bound to the object. Note that `this` can also be bound to just about anything in JavaScript. It's a different type of OOP.

Comment: And how do I extend that class?

Comment: @user899566: Using the `prototype` object. Set the `prototype` of the child class to an instance of the parent class. (Google: "prototypal inheritance")

Answer (score 2):

Unlike class-based languages, JavaScript is functional languages or prototypal language, you can't use `class` keyword or the kind of signature you have posted in JavaScript. In JavaScript, normally you would do:

```
function Person(){
  // public members
  this.foo = 'foo';
  this.walk = function(){ ......... }

  // private members
  var bar = 'bar';
  var baz = function(){.........}
}

var person = new Person();
```