# Reference for building Javascript library

Tags: javascript, oop, reference

I want to build my own Javascript library for this I need to master in OOP concepts to apply in Javascript. Please suggest me a reference which gives more examples with explanation.

Thank you in advance.
Shishir Kumar M.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript#1598077

Comment: Study some existing libraries that have the style you are after. jQuery, YUI, prototype are three examples that come to mind.  Write some code with each.  Step through several function calls into the library and watch how they work.  Study the source code.  IMO, that's the most powerful way to really learn.  If you don't consider yourself a pretty talented JS programmer, then when you have your first interface design, get some talented JS programmers to review your API and give you comments on it.  People who have consumed many APIs will know the most about what a good API should look like.

Comment: @jfriend00: I almost agree with your long comment, with one exception: I think it's not possible to get the idea of proper OOP by only reading another sources. It is still required to read books about architect (which are in most cases language-independent)

Comment: @zerkms - agreed.  I assumed the OP knew generic OOP concepts already, but perhaps not in JS.

Comment: @jfriend00 and zerkms thanks for the response. So any kind of reference to start up with for Architecture of OOP and DOM concepts ?

Comment: This is the link for the reference I found. (http://www.4shared.com/get/A5xM8NY0/javascript_-_the_definitive_gu.html). Anyone interested can use this link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick up some books on Javascript programming. I highly recommend O'Rielly's [Javascript The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805527) by David Flanagan or one of O'Rielly's many other books on Javascript. I personally learned a great deal from them.

Comment: This is the book I'd recommend.