# Objects chaining interrogations

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I spent some time on something I thought was a bug until I found a workaround.

Still I can't understand why the previous code failed.

Any insight please?

Failing code:

```
getModule: ->
  Gmaps4Rails.Google

createMap : ->
  new @getModule().Map()
```

Working code:

```
constructor:
  @module = @getModule()

getModule: ->
  Gmaps4Rails.Google

createMap : ->
  new @module.Map()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `new anonymous function` is not the same as `new Gmaps4Rails.Google()` in JavaScript.

```
// Translated JavaScript code (simplified):

var your_module = {
    getModule: function() {
        return Gmaps4Rails.Google;
    },
    createMap: function() {
        // This is where things go wrong
        return new this.getModule().Map();
    }
};
```

The problem is that `return new this.getModule().Map();` translates to `return new function() { return Gmaps4Rails.Google; }` - which *ignores* the return value and uses `this` (which is a new object inheriting from the anonymous function).  Thus the line essentially translates to `return {}.Map();` Since objects do not have a `Map` method, you get an error.

When you set `@module` to be a reference to `Gmaps4Rails.Google` then when you call `new @module.Map()` you are actually calling `new Gmaps4Rails.Google` - and it returns an object which has a `Map` method - thus everything works.

Comment: I'd have understood if I'd written: `new this.getModule.Map()` but it's not the case. This translates to: `return new function() { return Gmaps4Rails.Google; }()` I guess

Comment: @apneadiving - essentially - it would be closer to translate it as `var _temp = function() { return Gmaps4Rails.Google; }; return new _temp();`

Comment: So `this` inherits from `Gmaps4Rails.Google` then `this.Map()` is triggered? Sounds crazy to me :) (+1 in the meantime)

Comment: @apneadiving - no, not at all - in the broken version the returned value from the anonymous function (`this`) is an object that inherits from the anonymous function.  In the working version `@module` is a *reference* to the actual function you want to call `new` on (`Gmaps4Rails.Google`) rather than a different (anonymous) function altogether.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I guess it's te best answer I can get so I accept it, but do you know where I could find the theory around this please?

Comment: @apneadiving - [bobinc's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript/1598077#1598077) is quite good as is [killdream's article](http://killdream.github.com/blog/2011/10/understanding-javascript-oop/index.html#sec-4-1) and the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)