# Creation of Methods instance Javascript

Tags: javascript

I just started working on Javascript project. I know a couple of things

I have one js file called Employee and it has following methods:

1. AddEmployee
2. Search Employee
3. Third Employee

In Java, you access all the methods using object like employeeObj.addEmployee();
I want to achieve same thing in JavaScript. Meaning, I want to access all the methods by creating an employee object?

Comment: can you show us what you have so far? Generally if you want a good answer on this site it helps to show that you've put some effort in and to ask a specific question

Comment: I would suggest doing this small course http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript  You probably need chapter 7 and 8 but taking the whole course shouldn't take long and is the suggested way to go.

Comment: It is very hard for us to infer what your code looks like and suggest the correct strategy. Would you mind including some (sample, reduced case) code for that external file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "properly" create a custom object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

One of the way you can achieve OOP in Javascript

```
function Foo()
{
    this.x = 1;
}

Foo.prototype.AddX = function(y)    // Define Method
{
    this.x += y;
}

obj = new Foo;

obj.AddX(5);                        // Call Method
```

you can refer to few online tutorials for that

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript
2. http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm
3. http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs.shtml

Comment: Really? _THAT_ is how you do OOP in JavaScript? There are a million ways to do OOP in JavaScript, you have not suggested how you'd solve OP's issue. This is basically just a link to a bunch of tutorials.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Obviously, I suggested One of the way to achieve OO. May be I should rewrite my line. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to create objects in javascript.  If you just want a container for your functions the easiest way is to create a simple object with the functions as properties.

```
var employeeObj = {

  addEmployee: function(){
  },
  searchEmployee: function(){
  },
  thirdEmployee: function() {
  }
};
```

If you need the object to be able to reference itself during initial set up, you can use a constructor function

```
var Employee = function() {

}

Employee.prototype.addEmployee = function(){};
Employee.prototype.searchEmployee = function(){};
Employee.prototype.thirdEmployee = function(){};

var employeeObj = new Employee();
```

Comment: In the first option, the object can still reference itself. (you're assigning it to a variable after all.