# Clean Way to Build a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript

I am just starting with Javascript and I am not certain if I have declared these correct for an object type declaration. Is there a better way and more readable way to declare a variable as a class in Javascript or is this the simplest way.

**The blueObject is just and empty object from what I have read. Is this the only way to create a simple object type in Javascript or is there a better and more readable way?**

Code:

```
    var blueObject={}; //Creates and object 
    var redObject={};  //Creates and object

    blueObject.x=0;
    blueObject.y=200;
    blueObject.dx=2;
    blueObject.width=48;
    blueObject.height=48;
    blueObject.image=new Image();
    blueObject.image.src="blueplus.png";

    context.drawImage(blueObject.image, 0, 0);
    blueObject.blueImageData=context.getImageData(0, 0, blueObject.width,
                                                  blueObject.height);
    context.clearRect(0,0,theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);

    redObject.x=348;
    redObject.y=200;
    redObject.dx=-2;
    redObject.width=48;
    redObject.height=48;
    redObject.image=new Image();
    redObject.image.src="redcircle.png";
```

Comment: [There are a couple of ways to create objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Creating_new_objects). [Learn about constructor functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably the cleanest way for your purposes.

```
var blueObject = {
    x: 0,
    y: 200,
    dx: 2,
    width: 48,
    height: 48,
    image: new Image()
};

var redObject = {
    x: 348,
    y: 200,
    dx: -2,
    width: 48,
    height: 48,
    image: new Image();
};

blueObject.image.src = "blueplus.png";
redObject.image.src = "redCircle.png";

context.drawImage(blueObject.image, 0, 0);
blueObject.blueImageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, blueObject.width,
                                              blueObject.height);
context.clearRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1598077/2875073) to learn about more *formal* ways of creating a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Class Color like this :

```
ColorClass = function(aX, aY, ..., aSrc){
    this.x = aX;
    this.y = aY;
    ...
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = aSrc;
}
```

Then you can instanciate your two objects like this :

```
var blueObject = new ColorClass(0, 200, 2, ..., "blueplus.png"),
    redObject = new ColorClass(348, 200, ..., "redcircle.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the revealing module pattern that allows you to have a private scope. What you are doing is legal, but you are modifying the object from the outside which is often a bad practice.

```
var myClass = function(a, b){ // constructor
   var a = a;
   var b = b; 
   var c = a + b;

   return { // public signature
      c: c
   }
}();
```

Comment: Could you please adapt the concrete example to show for which parts of it the IEFE would be useful? `a+b` is a bit too abstract