# Can you assign the prototype of a Constructor to another Constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

Lets say you have a constructor ConstrA and want it to inherit from another constructor named SuperConstr and its prototype.

Can you simply do this:

```
SuperConstr = function() {};
SuperConstr.prototype.show = function (parm) {
    window.console.log(parm);
}
ConstrA = function () {
    this.value = 1;
}
ConstrA.prototype = SuperConstr.prototype; // <-----  Is this valid?
ConstrA.prototype.showAgain = function (parm) {
    window.console.log(parm * 2);
}
obj = new ConstrA();
obj.show(obj.value); // 1
obj.showAgain(obj.value); // 2
```

obj now appears to inherit from ConstrA and SuperConstr, but I'm not sure this is the right way to do this.

In other words, is the prototype of a constructor suppose to be equal (point to) the prototype of its constructor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1598077/251311

Comment: Setting the prototype is half the part of inheritance in JavaScript; you may want to re use the parent constructor as well. And as Alex pointed out is that you better not just assign it like you did, more info here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's valid, but you no longer have two prototype objects, just the one.

So any methods you're trying to delegate won't actually be delegated, they will all exist on `SuperConstr`'s `prototype` object.

A concern with this is that if you extend `ConstrA`'s prototype, you're actually assigning to `SuperContr`'s prototype, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: So each constructor should have it's own prototype so that you can add items to ConstrA's prototype, for example, without causing them to be added to SuperConstr's prototype or any objects instantiated off of it.  That makes sense.  Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisG. No worries. JavaScript delegation is confusing and still gets me. Good luck.