# Inheritance with Lo-Dash

Tags: javascript, inheritance, lodash

I am trying to emulate inheritance in javascript using a the Lo-Dash javascript library.

I am simply using _.extend to do so:

```
function Parent() {
  var self = this;

  self.hello = function () {
    console.log('Hello from parent');
  };
}

function Child() {
  var self = this;

  _.extend(self, Parent);
}

Child.hello(); // Doesn't exist
```

I thought this would work since all javascript functions are objects but obviously I am wrong. Why doesn't this work and how would I properly emulate inheritance using Lo-Dash?

Comment: That happens because function `Child` doesn't have `hello` property. See [How to “properly” create a custom object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1598077/251311)

Comment: Even if you did it correctly you would not really inherit but just copy members of one onto another (more like mix in) for a detailed answer about JavaScript inheritance you can view this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parent is simply the constructor for the Parent class, it does not itself have the `hello` property that it adds to `self`. You could just change the `_.extend` line to this: `_.extend(self, new Parent())` to solve it. This works because the object *returned* by `new Parent()` does have a `hello` property that `_.extend` can copy over to `self`.

To access the `hello` property you will also have to create an *instance* of the `Child` class rather than accessing `hello` on the constructor. After making the above change, `(new Child()).hello()` should work because you accessing the `hello` property on the `Child` *instance* not the *constructor*.

But, this seems to me to be a poor solution because `new Child() instanceof Parent` will return `false`. If you want to properly set up the prototype chain so there is "true" inheritance going on you should read about psuedoclassical and prototypal inheritance.

Answer (score 13):

[See _.create documentation](http://lodash.com/docs#create) for a working example.

Comment: This best answers the question because it is what the method was designed for - https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/663

Comment: this is a link-only answer

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`_.create()`](http://lodash.com/docs#create) function and `prototype` to emulate inheritance.

```
function Parent() {}

Parent.prototype.hello = function() {
    console.log('Hello from parent');
};

function Child() {}

Child.prototype = _.create(Parent.prototype, {
    'constructor': Child
});

var child = new Child();
child.hello(); //Hello from parent
```