# Object Oriented, inheritance in javascript unable to call external methods

Tags: javascript, oop, refactoring

I would like to refactor my working code to a better structured javascript. At this moment I have something like this:

```
function Search(){
    addNode = function(nodeToAdd){
        //do something
    }
    function update(){
        var node = aKindOfObjectFromSomeLibrary;
        node.on('click', function(d){
            $.each(someArray, function(i){
                addNode(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The objective is to create a Search object with it method that can be used even outside like this:

```
var s = new Search();
s.addNode(nodeToAdd);
```

I was thinking about doing this:

```
function Search(){
    this.addNode = function(nodeToAdd){}
}
```

But then the function addNode will be not accessible inside a nested generic function.

Another way I was studying is the use of this structure:

```
(function(){
    var object = {
        var field = itsValue,
        addNode : function(){}
    };
)();
```

But of course the problem of recalling the method inside a nested structure still remains.

Can you please direct me to the correct way of refactoring my code, is the only way to have that working to pass a

```
var scope = this
```

inside the nested function?

I am also referring to this Q&A in stackoverflow:
[How to "properly" create a custom object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript?answertab=votes#tab-top)

With the difference that, by now, I don't have to subclass my object (and this is the reason why I tried the

```
(function(){})();
```

closure structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zio, try to structure this way

```
var util = {

Search : function(node) {
        this.addNode(node);
    },



   addNode : function(node) {

    // do something

}
```

and when you want to call the function you do:

```
util.Search(nodetoadd);
```

but I suggest not to create a function search that just simply call another function (addNode)

Just do:

```
var util = {

   addNode : function(node) {

        // do something

    }
```

and call it:

```
util.addNode(nodetoadd);
```

Comment: Search is just the name of the object, not a function that itself will search something... The object will also contain other fields and many other methods, I think the util "static" class is not what I need.