# Understanding module design pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am not very good in JavaScript. so when I saw a block of code now then many area is not clear. So someone please help me to understand.

I know this below way people declare their module

```
var Module = (function () {
  var privateMethod = function () {
    //A Private Method
    var privatemember; // scope is only private method
  };
  return {
    publicMethod: function () {
      //you can call private method here.
    }
  };
})();

Module.publicMethod(); //works
```

Just I saw another bit different code for module pattern as follows where knockout.js is used.

```
var HMS = HMS || {};

$(function () {

    HMS.PatientModel = function () {
        this.Patient_Name = ko.observable();
        this.Patient_Address = ko.observable();
    };

    HMS.PatientViewModel = function () {
        var patient = ko.observable(),
        loadPatient = function () {
            var newModel = new HMS.PatientModel();
            newModel.Patient_Name("Premkumar");
            patient(newModel);
        };
        return {
            patient: patient,
            loadPatient: loadPatient
        };
    } ();


    HMS.PatientViewModel.loadPatient();

    ko.applyBindings(HMS.PatientViewModel);

});
```

1) What is this code `var HMS = HMS || {};` ?

2) See this `$(function () {}) ();`

Why module has no name specific. see my first code where I give a name to my module like this way `var Module = (function () {}) ()`

3) Inside module code every function name has started with `HMS`.............why like `HMS.PatientModel = function () { };`

Please help me to understand the second set code point wise. Thanks

Comment: curios to ask multiple question, but did you research for each individually?

Comment: i am not advance js developer. so the code which i highlighted here was confusing me. so i asked and looking for some one help. thanks

Comment: I'll give you a quick answer. If you're interested in research.

Comment: Are you familiar with JS logical values `truthy` and `falsey`?  Do you know how JS variables scoped and what `closures` are?

Comment: if possible redirect me to right article from where i can acquire the knowledge of JS variables scoped & closures. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var HMS = HMS || {};
```

that expression defines the var HMS to HMS or empty object if it is not defined is a short hand for

```
if(HMS) {
  var HMS = HMS;
} else {
  var HMS = {};
}
```

2) You are creating an object from an IIFE

They are declaring and empty object if it does not exist, and decorating it with the methods/functions once the function below its executed. 
is the same as this:

```
var HMS = {
   PatientModel : function () {},
   PatientViewModel : function () {}, 
}
```

3) And that is why they use HMS inside the function.

```
var HMS = {};
HMS.PatientModel = function() {};
HMS.PatientViewModel = function() {};
```

You should read about  [Closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work), [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript), and [How to “properly” create a custom object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript)

Sample and short explanation of closure:

A closure is when you have access to variables that are not in the lexical scope of the function For example, a function declared inside another function, will have access to the parent variables.

eg:

```
(function(){
    var a = 1;

    function mainFunction() {

        function innerFunction() {
            var b = 2

            function subFunction() {
                console.log(a); //We have access to "a" here.
                console.log(b); //We have access to "b" here.
            }

           subFunction();
        }


        innerFunction();
        console.log(a); //We have access to "a" here.
        console.log(b); //We dont have access to "b" here. //error
    }
    mainFunction();

})();
console.log(a);  //We dont have access to "a" here. //error
```

Comment: the code i posted related to module design pattern if yes then why they did not specify any name for his module ?

Comment: does the  Closures mean when a main function will have inner function then inner function will be called  Closures? am i right ?

Comment: I should post a closure example give me a minute.

Comment: I've updated the example but basically a closure is when you create a function inside a function, the inner function should have access to the parent scope variables. I recomend to you to read the linked "closures" link is better explained there.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) what is this code var HMS = HMS || {}; ?

If HMS is undefined HMS is to be equal to an empty object otherwise use HMS as is (in your case HMS is an object).

> 2) see this $(function () {}) ();

It's called [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript).

> 3) why like HMS.PatientModel = function () { };

HMS is an object and just adding its property with value. Value may be anything.

> 4) From your comment in another answer, why they didn't define module name?

They have defined the module name as Module. See `var Module = (function(){}());`

Comment: this is from `var Module = (function(){}());` 1st set code and i am curious about second set code. 1st set code i understand. thanks

Comment: does the  Closures mean when a main function will have inner function then inner function will be called  Closures? am i right ?