# Access private static object and method

Tags: javascript, object, scope

I was reading about the best methods to create objects in javascript and found an interesting solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1597560/2011284).

```
var Foo = function()
{

    var privateStaticMethod = function() {};
    var privateStaticVariable = "foo";

    var constructor = function Foo(foo, bar)
    {
        var privateMethod = function() {};
        this.publicMethod = function() {};
    };

    constructor.publicStaticMethod = function() {};

    return constructor;
}();
```

I have been playing with this structure but I was wondering how can I do a few things.

- How can I access `privateStaticVariable` or `privateStaticMethod` from within `constructor.publicStaticMethod`?
- If I create a second public method like `constructor.secondPublicStaticMethod  = function(){};`,  how can I access it from within `constructor.publicStaticMethod`?
- If I was to instantiate this object, how could I access all static properties and methods from within `constructor`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I access `privateStaticVariable` or `privateStaticMethod` from within `constructor.publicStaticMethod`

You can access them simply by using their names because they are enclosed variables within `constructor.publicStaticMethod` because of [the closure property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

> If I create a second public method like `constructor.secondPublicStaticMethod  = function(){};`, how can I access it from within `constructor.publicStaticMethod`

Since `secondPublicStaticMethod` is a function defined on the `constructor` object, you can simply invoke it like `constructor.secondPublicStaticMethod`

> If I was to instantiate this object, how could I access all static properties and methods from within `constructor`

This is similar to the above mentioned. You can access `privateStaticVariable` and `privateStaticMethod` simply by writing `privateStaticVariable` and `privateStaticMethod` respectively. And the functions defined on `constructor` can be accessed with `constructor.publicStaticMethod`