# How can I create an object with constructor function in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create a new object working like `Date` or `Array` in JavaScript, which can be called like a function `Date()`. Meanwhile, there are also other functions on it like `Date.now()` or `Array.of()`, which returns a new instance of this object.

How can I do that?

For example:

```
function Foo (lastName) {
    this.firstName = 'Foo'
    return this.firstName + ' ' + lastName
}

Foo('Bar') // 'Foo Bar'

Foo.setFirstName = function (firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName
    /**
     * Here I want to return a new instance of Foo, with new firstName
     */
}

const foo = Foo.setFirstName('foo')

foo('bar') // 'foo bar'
```

Comment: Check this article https://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "properly" create a custom object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Foo (lastName) {
    this.firstName = 'Foo'
    return this.firstName + ' ' + lastName
}

Foo('Bar') // 'Foo Bar'
console.log(Foo('Bar') )

Foo.setFirstName = function (firstName) {
return function(lastName) {
   this.firstName = firstName;
   return this.firstName + ' ' + lastName
}
}

const foo = Foo.setFirstName('foo')

foo('bar') // 'foo bar'
console.log(foo('bar'));
```

Comment: I updated the question. Actually I want the new instance to have the same functions but different context with the original function. How can I do that?

Comment: @KarlBao updated the answer to your need.it may help

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Foo(lastName) {
  this.firstName = 'Foo'
  this.lastName = lastName;
  return this;
}

Foo('Bar') // {firstName:'Foo', lastName:'Bar'}

Foo.setFirstName = function(firstName) {
  let k = Object.assign({}, this);
  return Object.assign(k, {
    "firstName": firstName
  })
}

const foo = Foo.setFirstName('foo') //{firstName:'foo', lastName:'Bar'}
```

Object.assign will create new object as per first argument and append the  properties from previous object, and we use Object.assign second time in order to override the properties as per our argument