# Where does the component comes from?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qt5

I'm taking a look at the Qt installer framework, particularly the [Start Menu Shortcut Example](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/qtinstallerframework-startmenu-packages-org-qtproject-ifw-example-meta-installscript-qs.html) where I found

```
function Component()
{
    // default constructor
}

Component.prototype.createOperations = function()
{
    // call default implementation to actually install README.txt!
    component.createOperations();

    if (systemInfo.productType === "windows") {
        component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", "@TargetDir@/README.txt", "@StartMenuDir@/README.lnk",
            "workingDirectory=@TargetDir@", "iconPath=%SystemRoot%/system32/SHELL32.dll",
            "iconId=2", "description=Open README file");
    }
}
```

Looks like javascript (or Qt script) is in use here and I'm a little lost. In the code above, where does `compoent` comes from? Is it created by the `function Component(){}`?

I found [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting.html) saying

> The script has to contain a Component object that the installer
> creates when it loads the script. Therefore, the script must contain
> at least the Component() function, which performs initialization

Is `function Component(){}` kind of a constructor?

Comment: It is a constructor. A constructor function allows the assignment of `prototypes` to the object that will be constructed from the _constructor function_ using the `new` keyword.

Comment: May I ask you to expand on the "A constructor function allows the assignment of prototypes" part? Does it mean it necessary to call it in order for the "Component.prototype.createOperations = function() {...}" part to be executed?

Comment: This answer should satisfy your question in more detail (and snarky distaste for JavaScript) than you will need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595611/how-to-properly-create-a-custom-object-in-javascript/1598077#1598077